# how to set QLayout margins and spacing to be high-DPI aware

Tags: qt

In my application I am using certain adjustments to default `QLayout` contents margins and spacing, e.g. `setContentsMargins(4, 4, 4, 4)` to make them a bit smaller than the default values, which are too big. The adjusted values look perfect on normal full HD display, but the margins looks too narrow on 4K display. What is the best practice for setting margins and spacing for `QLayout` derived classes so that they are aware of high DPI?

Comment: Rather than using fixed numbers, you could use a percentage of the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several solutions and now I am using something like this:

```
int layoutMargin(qreal multiplier)
{
    return qRound(QApplication::style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_LayoutLeftMargin) * multiplier);
}

int layoutSpacing(qreal multiplier)
{
    return qRound(QApplication::style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_LayoutVerticalSpacing) * multiplier);
}

int m = layoutMargins(0.5);
layout->setContentsMargins(m, m, m, m);

int s = layoutSpacing(0.5);
layout->setSpacing(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use relative units with stylesheets to achieve this. Like:

```
* { margin: 0.2em }
```

The advantage would be you can use this approach in QDesigner as well. But as you can only set Stylesheets on QWidgets (not QLayouts) this would need changes in your UI-Tree.

An alternative to enable **High-DPI support on pixel-bound** sizes is to switch a converter in between. This way you can use your old values (i.e. "4") which will scale in respect to the screen-dpi setting.

```
int CGuiHelper::scaleDpi(int inputPixel)
{
  qreal dpiDefault  = 96.0f;
  qreal dpiCurrent = QApplication::screens().at(0)->logicalDotsPerInch();

  // Typical values for Windows are: 96dpi=100%, 120dpi=125% 144dpi=150%, 192dpi=200%
  return static_cast<int>(dpiCurrent / dpiDefault * inputPixel);
}
```